# How to render interactive components like edittext, drop-down in server driven ui and send user entered values back to server by tap on button

Tags: android, kotlin, components, android-jetpack-compose, dynamic-ui

How to render interactive components like edittext, drop-down in server driven ui and send user entered values of that components back to server by clicking on button on jetpack compose and what will be the sample json for this case scenario?

I am able to render text, image not user interactive components from server driven ui but unable to use user interactive components.

Comment: You can place a boolean flag on the server JSON response when it is received in the app. It will parse the JSON and make the flag visible based on that to show edit text etc.

Comment: That's not how mobile development is supposed to work. It's best if the server and client (android) only send and receive pure data. This is by design for offline support and efficiency. Instead you can send only configuration data like a boolean and show or hide view based on that value.